# WordPress Javascript in Admin not working unless WP_DEBUG set to True

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I have migrated a WordPress website from one server to another and changed the URL in the correct places in the database.

The website uses w3 Total Cache and on the new server the Javascript does not work in the admin dashboard (no tabs working or editor showing on pages/posts/products).

I presumed this was a w3Total Cache issue so I removed it the correct way, removing all the w3 files in /wp-content/ and I the Javascript still does not working the admin.

TRIED SOLUTION 1:

1. Deactivate ALL plugins
2. I switched on WP_DEBUG to True but still no Javascript working and no errors.

SOLUTION 2.

1. I noticed the line //define('WP_CACHE', true); // Added by W3 Total Cache in wp-config.php
2. I removed the // from the above line and Now I get the error message below and Now the Javascript works in the Admin!

   ```
   Warning: include(/home/x/public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/x/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 65
   ```

   'Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/x/public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/x/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 65'

If I Remove the line `define('WP_CACHE', true);` the Javascript does Not work again.

If I Leave the line `define('WP_CACHE', true);` and set to False `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` the Javascript does not work.

I am very confused there is Zero reference to w3 Total Cache on the website, I have removed it from all places on the server.

Anyone had this issue before?

Thanks

Scott.

Comment: Right now I'm having the exact same issue with my website. I'm also suspecting that it's because of W3 Total Cache plugin.